# Assembly to C code

Tags: c, assembly

This Assembly code:

```
cmp [Variable1], 10
jae AlternateBlock
call SomeFunction
jmp AfterIfBlock
cmp [Variable1], 345
jne AfterIfBlock
call SomeOtherFunction
```

equals to this C code?:

```
if (variable1 >= 10)
{
    goto AlternateBlock;
    SomeFunction();
    goto AfterIfBlock;
}
else if (Variable1 != 345)
{
    goto AfterIfBlock;
    SomeOtherFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

More succinctly:

```
if( variable1 < 10 ) {
  SomeFunction();
} else if( variable1 == 345 ) {
  SomeOtherFunction()
}
```

Explanation:

```
cmp [Variable1], 10
jae AlternateBlock     ; if variable1 is >= 10 then go to alternate block
call SomeFunction      ; else fall through and call SomeFunction(). ie. when variable1 < 10
jmp AfterIfBlock       ; prevent falling through to next conditional
cmp [Variable1], 345
jne AfterIfBlock       ; if variable1 is not equal to 345 then jump to afterifblock
call SomeOtherFunction ; else fall through to call SomeOtherFunction
```

If you take some time to understand it you should see it's semantically equivalent to the C code. Perhaps this helps.

```
cmp [Variable1], 10
jb @f
call SomeFunction
jmp end
  @@:
cmp [Variable1], 345
jnz end
call SomeOtherFunction
  end:
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it's probably more like this:

```
if (variable1 < 10)
    SomeFunction();
else if (Variable1 == 345)
    SomeOtherFunction();
```

But you've not included the labels in your assembler so I can't be sure. I've assumed the labels are like this:

```
    cmp [Variable1], 10
    jae AlternateBlock
    call SomeFunction
    jmp AfterIfBlock
@@AlternateBlock:
    cmp [Variable1], 345
    jne AfterIfBlock
    call SomeOtherFunction
@@AfterIfBlock:
```

Comment: @Mike Yes I've just spotted that when checking through again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. If `variable1` is less than 10, the assembly code will call `SomeFunction`, and the C code will not, it will jump to `AlternateBlock`

Comment: But why is it; if variable1 < 10, jae isn't jump if above or equal?

Comment: @Thanos: Yes, so  bacause variable is less than 10, it will NOT jump anywhere and will go to the next statement, which is call someFunction

Comment: I mean that JAE isn't if (>=)?

Comment: @Thanos JAE is indeed jump if greater than or equals. Think about it!

Comment: Oh yes, now I understood, I have been stuck for a moment, thank you.

Comment: @Thamos. `JAE label` and then `Call someFunc` means `if(variable >=10) { goto label; } SomeFunc();`. That is, if variable was less than 10, no jump will occur and someFunc will be called